# How can I get PivotTable Row and Column labels to change from their default value using Aspose Cells?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-interop, aspose-cells

I am creating row and column pivot fields like so:

```
pivotTable.AddFieldToArea(Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotFieldType.Row, DESCRIPTION_COLUMN);
pivotTable.AddFieldToArea(Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotFieldType.Column, MONTHYR_COLUMN);
```

This works, but uses generic text for the labels, specifically "Row Labels" and "Column Labels." I want to provide my own labels to replace those. Using Excel Interop, I can do that as follows:

```
// This changes the label from "Column Labels"
pivotTable.CompactLayoutColumnHeader = "Months";
// This changes the label from "Row Labels"
pivotTable.CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Description";
```

I can't use Excel Interop for some of these reports, though, because it is so slow converting large amounts of data to a PivotTable that it makes sloths look like cheetahs and molasses appear to be moving at the speed of light. What literally took several hours to generate with Excel Interop took 21 minutes using Aspose Cells.

So what is the equivalent of "CompactLayoutColumnHeader" in Aspose Cells? Hopefully something that makes its intent a little clearer (who would think that "CompactLayoutColumnHeader" would be the property to which to assign a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across the answer; it is much more straightforward in Aspose.Cells than Excel Interop (unsurprisingly):

```
pivotTable.ColumnHeaderCaption = "Months";
pivotTable.RowHeaderCaption = "Description";
```